# Valid sdkVersion for slideme.org

Tags: android, manifest

I am trying to upload an apk to slidme.org

```
http://slideme.org/node/add/mobileapp
```

But I get this validation failing

> Your application must have a valid sdkVersion set. You need to edit
>   your AndroidManifest.xml file to fix this, and then upload again the
>   .apk file.

What is the problem with my manifest ?

```
<application
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Start" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="7" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and solve it by:
remove:

```
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 28
```

from gradle.
and adding :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
```

to manifest.
It seems slideme isn't up to date...

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by removing minSdkVersion. and refered targetSdkVersion to min version.
So in your case it will become