# App Upload to Slideme - Valid targetSdkVersion not set error

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, android-manifest

I am trying to upload my first app to Slideme and am running into the following error:
Your application must have a valid targetSdkVersion set. To solve this problem, you need to edit your AndroidManifest.xml file and upload again the .apk file.

So I added targetSdkVersion to my manifest file and removed it from my gradle file and still no luck. I also tried it again with the targetSdkVersion still set in the gradle file but also no luck. I've played around quite a but but I keep getting the same error. I've reset android studio multiple times and I've tried closing and re-opening the slideme upload web page with no change.

Here is my manifest.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.cards.doublerun">

        <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="29" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".GameActivity"/>
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

And here is my Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cards.doublerun"
        minSdkVersion 15
        //targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

I've looked at this question: [Why does AndroidManifest.xml have invalid targetSdkVersion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51456516/why-does-androidmanifest-xml-have-invalid-targetsdkversion/51456893) 
and this question: [Valid sdkVersion for slideme.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617684/valid-sdkversion-for-slideme-org/51456862#51456862) 
but the advice that is provided in both isn't working for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have multiple modules inside the app? there might be a problem with them

Comment: You'll have to pardon my ignorance but I don't think so... I do have two activities though.This is a super basic app. I should note however, that I got it to work when I changed the target value to 15 but that I can't get it to work with a targetSdkValue of 29. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

have you tryied by adding updated sdk version in  Gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.stackoverflowpratice"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

this will work.

Comment: How is this different from my grade file posted in the original question?

Comment: in your gradel file you removed  //targetSdkVersion 29  it is needed for publish apk  @JackDuane

Comment: I removed it because Slideme *requires* that it be in the manifest file. Which is what I stated in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this into your manifest file

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="29"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I replied here if anyone still need to solve this issue.
If you are using Unity, set Target API Level in Other Setting to one specific API instead of Automatic
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXOuI.png)